# Previously denied entry from Canada to USA. Does that technically count as setting foot "on US soil"?

Tags: usa, canada, borders

15 years ago, we decided on a whim to get lunch in the USA as we were passing near the frontier on a road trip in Canada. We did not know the exact requirements, and as we lacked an address of destination and US currency  we were refused entry by the US officer. 
After filling some forms, the officer showed us the roundabout on the US side, told us to go around it and go back to Canada. I remember him insisting **"you have *never* been to the US"**, I found it strange, as de facto we were on US soil, even so for a few minutes.

Two years after that we immigrated to Canada, we've been citizen of this country for 10 years or so. 
My question is *not* about the risk of being scrutinized or denied entry when I go back there –I found plenty of answers here about it– but specifically what I should answer if a border  officer ask me **"Have you ever put foot on US soil?"**

I feel that if answer "yes" I might get accused of lying (as contradicting the imperious statement of the previous officer)  but if say "no" I'll be accused of the same thing as I, indeed, in reality, physically been to this country before.

(I've considered explaining the situation, but my experience of talking to these border control agents is that they don't like complicated stories, that make them go paranoid.)

Comment: I think the original CBP officer answered your question earlier ... "you have never been to the US" ... in other words he didn't enter your details into his computer system, so there is not record of you entering or being refused entry.  Therefore no record to be contradicted.  And no I can't provide any links to document my theorem.

Comment: Most likely, INS allowed you to withdraw your application to enter, then turned you around.  This happens all the time.  It's highly unlikely an office is going to try to 'trap' you in this minutia.  You never officially entered the US.

Comment: If you were in a car, your feet never touched US soil. And if it was on a hard paved road surface, it wasn't even soil.

Comment: The more likely question, IMHO, is  "have you ever been refused entry to the US?". Your question does not sound like anything I've heard asked of a Canadian by a US border agent.

Comment: It sounds like the CBP officer was looking forward, and was *specifically giving you instructions for this here exact situation*.

Comment: @GrahamBorland that kind of logic is rarely a good idea with border guards, or police, or anyone in a position of authority.  It just *might* work with a judge, but you certainly don't want it to get to that point, since you would spend hours or even days in detention before seeing a judge.

Comment: If you've ever visited the Kennedy memorial at Runnymede, near London, UK, then technically you would have set foot on US soil. The US is also the biggest exporter of sand, so if you've ever stood on a man made beach somewhere, then there's a chance that you would technically have stood on US soil ;-)

Comment: Did you leave the car on the US side? This should technically answer the question.

Comment: I know loopholes and tricky wording are fun, but how about leaving that for cases where being banned from a country (or ending up in a detention center for a bit) isn't a possible option.

Comment: On a related note, what should you say if a border officer asks whether you have stopped murdering kittens yet?

Comment: Answer yes, then if they don't find any records of you, just say you once visited a US embassy. :P Just kidding.

Comment: @Strawberry - this is a misconception. The JFK memorial at Runnymede is owned by the US government, but only in the same way that many people in the UK may own their own homes. It is their _property_, but it is still the territory of and a part of the United Kingdom, in terms of sovereignty. There are actually places where what you allude to is the case (the tomb of Suleyman Shah in Syria is literally sovereign Turkish territory, for example) but they are quite rare and I am not aware of any in the UK.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto this is another misconception, embassies are the not the territory of the country they belong to, they remain the territory of the country in which they are located.

Comment: @IvanMcA interesting. I read the page that has been linked on the topic after writing my comment.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Have you ever put foot on US soil?

Yes. You were on US soil. If you committed a crime you would have been prosecuted under the US judicial system. If you died a US coroner would have issued a death certificate saying you died in the US.

However, a border guard will never ask this question. They'll ask:

> Have you ever visited the US before?

or perhaps

> Have you ever been to the US before?

"No" would be your answer. While you were technically on US soil from a customs perspective you were denied entry and never "entered" or "visited" the US. It's like your vehicle was magically turned around before it actually crossed the border. Even though for practical reasons they had to allow you onto US soil.

I would also add that I don't think a border guard would ever use the term "soil" as too many people would ([mistakenly](https://pathtoforeignservice.com/is-an-embassy-on-foreign-soil-the-sovereign-territory-of-the-host-country-or-the-embassys-country/)) believe that if they've ever been to a US embassy that they have put foot on US soil.

EDIT: I think the "you have never been to the US" comment the officer made has to do with international law. By refusing you entry and sending you back to Canadian customs the Canadians must deal with you. They can not refuse you entry and send you back to the US. Canada can either permit you entry or possibly if your visa has expired detain and deport you back to your home country but legally it's as if you never set foot on US soil.

Rather then saying "you have never been to the US" the officer should probably have said "When you get to Canadian Customs tell them you were denied entry to the US".

Comment: Welcome to Travel; excellent first answer! I think many of us got a bit of tunnel vision and didn't notice that the question was just something the OP hypothetically imagined a border guard _might_ ask.

Comment: Most crimes are prosecuted under the judicial system of the state inwhich they are committed, and while there is of course a sense in which this can be considered "the US judicial system," I can imagine a particularly misguided argument that someone not yet "admitted" by CBP could somehow be legally in (e.g.) Vermont without being in the US.

Comment: @phoog - By US judicial system I just meant US vs Canadian. I would also imagine that most border crimes (smuggling, assaulting a border guard, etc.) are prosecuted in federal court. It does bring up the interesting questions though of what happens if I litter at a border crossing just after I've been admitted to the US? It's too late to deny me entry. Can you deport someone for littering? Can a border guard even write a ticket for littering or would they have to detain me and call the state troopers? Am I likely to get away with it because it's way too much paperwork?

Comment: You're likely to get away with it because it's too much paperwork, just as in many (if not most) US jurisdictions. Even if you're prosecuted for it, it's not generally by itself going to make you inadmissible or deportable.  To answer the generalquestion, though, federal officers will call local police of there is a violation of state law by someone who hasn't also violated federal law.

Comment: Great answer, John. Question: how is this U-turn at the Canada/US border different from entering a U.S. embassy? Just want to stimulate a different, perhaps useful angle on it.

Comment: Another angle: suppose you're a visitor to Canada who has applied to become a resident from inside Canada. You got your papers and now have to leave Canada and re-enter in order to complete the process. Many people do this by "going around the flagpole" at the Canada/US border.  **If the US denies you entry, can you still complete the "around the flagpole" process to enter Canada as a newly accepted permanent resident?** (I realize that this may be beyond the scope of the travel stackexchange!)

Comment: @Kaz - A US embassy is not sovereign territory of the United States (US soil). It belongs to the host nation. An embassy enjoys wide immunity under the Vienna Convention and for most practical purposes acts like US soil but has subtle differences. For example a baby born at a US embassy does not get American citizenship because it was not born on US soil.

Comment: @Kaz - It looks like the around the flag pole (with entry denied) might not work because the Canadians/Americans share customs data on non Canada/US citizens. So the Canadian border guard would know you didn't visit the US. http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/btb-pdf/ebsiip-asfipi-eng.html

Comment: @JohnRay Good point; and I think that would also be obvious to them from the lack of stamps in your passport.

Answer (score 50):

Doing a U-turn and coming back into Canada does not constitute any time spent in the United States. Your answer to their question is a simple "No". If they ask further and want more detail you can embellish them.

"No" is the simple and factual answer of the matter. You have not ever been into the USA as a visiting traveller. A few hundred feet in order to immediately turn around because you have not been granted access certainly does not count.

You were not given clearance at that time, so the answer is "No".

"No. No. No!"

Comment: Well, a few hundred feet _would_ count _if you had been admitted to the country._ But, since OP was not admitted, legally speaking, OP has never entered the U.S. and it's perfectly correct to answer as such to anyone who asks, including border agents. If they further ask if you've ever been denied entry, then OP would need to mention the incident at the land border.

Comment: @reirab, fair enough, that is a good point. I'll be a bit more specific.

Comment: I'd love some source on that.

Comment: @P.O. a source on what specifically?

Comment: I think you mean [indulge](https://www.google.com/search?q=indulge&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), not [embellish](https://www.google.com/search?q=embellish&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). I suspect that making the incident *more* interesting to an immigration officer is not the end goal. ;) (To say nothing of the fact that embellish sometimes implies that you've added things that didn't actually happen to the story!)

Comment: @jpmc, you might indulge the officer. I would embellish the details.

Comment: This. Especially given that, in OP's situation, the officer very clearly said this.

Comment: @reirab Or, if you had penetrated barriers covertly — which one would presumably never admit, except possibly under duress.

Comment: The term "embellish" when used in the context of facts or details means that you're adding additional details that are untrue, so that doesn't seem to be the correct term. I think the appropriate word here is "elaborate".

Comment: @Cronax Well, in the specific usage here, jpmc is correct that 'indulge' is probably what was meant. 'Elaborate' would work if you remove the 'them' after it, though.

Comment: @reirab What was meant and what is appropriate is not necessarily the same thing ;)

Comment: @Cronax 'Indulge' actually is appropriate. "To indulge him/her/them" is an idiom meaning to do or provide what was asked for by him/her/them. 'Elaborate' wouldn't work, as it's intransitive. It would work if you removed the 'them,' though.

Comment: @reirab I think there might be a missing "s" on "details" based on Octopus' response. "Elaborate" would make more sense if "them" refers to the details. I assumed it referred to the officer(s) since "detail" is singular, but "indulge the officer" and "elaborate on the details" both work fine. Either way, though, "embellish" seems to be something you *don't* want to do. Sticking to the facts and making the story as boring as possible is the way to go.

Answer (score 14):

> Have you ever put foot on US soil?

No, I was turned around to Canada by road in 2002.

Let them decide what to regard that as

Comment: my experience with them is that they might perceive that as being cocky ("I asked you to answer "yes " or "no" ").

Comment: @P.O. see the update :)

Comment: Telling them that you were refused entry before is a really good way of being scrutinized in detail. You really don't want to end up doing that if at all possible.

Comment: exactly my fear

Comment: Isn't the point that you were NOT refused entry, you were turned around and allowed to withdraw your attempt.

Comment: @JamesRyan and @Octopus there are a lot of "let's suppose" items in this question. For example the title starts with `Previously **denied** entry from Canada to USA`.

Comment: Good point, the border officer filled up some form and I don't remember if I was "denied" or "allowed to withdraw"...

Comment: As for the "put foot on US soil" it's the first phrase that came to my mind, put it could be "have you been to the US" or anything similar.

Answer (score 3):

You did not enter the US, you entered the border zone between the nations which technically is a grey area controlled jointly by both.
It's a thin line on the map, but large enough for some fences, guard shacks, parking lots, and that area you made a U-turn in.

Comment: That's not how it works at most borders, the area "between" the border gates and respective immigration controls is still part of one or other country. The border usually runs down the middle and one side is one country and the other is the other. But it is a line, and you can often see it if you look, it is often explicitly marked, but even if it isn't you can look for a change in the road surface, etc. which is usually an indicator. There can be "border zones" like this, but the norm for border crossings is a very specific point that is the actual border.

Comment: The term for what @jwenting is talking about is called a limitrophe - see Breyer's dissent in Hernadeza v Mesa (a recent US Supreme Court case) at https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/16pdf/15-118_97bf.pdf (last handful of pages). It is a somewhat unsettled question about whether the border is the imaginary line or the space about the border.